# How to remove event filters when filterEvents() is used?

Tags: scalafx, rx-scala

Hello I want to use rxscala and scalafx together so I did this to re-package mouse events:

```
def mouseEvents: Observable[MouseEvent] = Observable.create(observer => {
  stage.filterEvent(MouseEvent.Any)((event: MouseEvent) => {
    observer.onNext(event)
    event.consume
  })
  Subscription { ??? }
})
```

The problem is that inside the `Subscription { ??? }` block I want to remove the event filter that was registered by `filterEvent()` but looking at it I see that `filterEvent()` doesn't keep a reference to the event filter so I can't use `stage.removeEventFilter()`. I don't see a `removeFilterEvent()` equivalent either, so how are event filters registered using `filterEvent()` removed?

I guess a workaround is not to use `filterEvent()` and instead use the javafx's `addEventFilter()` but the syntax is worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can use `addEventFilter(eventType, eventHandler)` and `removeEventFilter(eventType, eventHandler)`.

In the latest **ScalaFX 1.0.0-M8-SNAPSHOT** method `filterEvent` returns subscription as expected. (see [ScalaFX Issue 115](https://code.google.com/p/scalafx/issues/detail?id=115))